Elastic Serach: how to write script for "sort" keyword
I want to come first one data, so I use "script" to custom order
      "sort": [
        {
            "_script": {
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "String country_code = doc['country_code'].value; long res = 0; if (country_code == params['multiplier']) { res =  0; } else { res = 1; }",
                    "params": {
                        "multiplier": "OTHER_COUNTRY"
                    }
                },
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },

But in "Source" always return 1
I don't understand this problem. Thanks for reading

Can Try this
"sort": [
{
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "String country_code = doc['country_code'].value; if (country_code == params['multiplier']) { return 0; } else { return 1; }",
            "params": {
                "multiplier": "OTHER_COUNTRY"
            }
        },
        "order": "asc"
    }
}

]

It do not work, I tried it before...

"sort": [
{
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """
                def country_code = doc['country_code.keyword'].value;
                if (country_code == params.multiplier) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            """,
            "params": {
                "multiplier": "OTHER_COUNTRY"
            }
        },
        "order": "asc"
    }
}

]
Is your requirment is this what i understand from your logic i.e. If country_code is "OTHER_COUNTRY", set the sort value to 0. Otherwise, set it to 1.
If NOT, Please provide your requirement clealy.
